# Network sniffer that opens the ips as tabs in browser?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, tshark, setuid, pyshark

I'm trying to write a code that basically grabs the network traffic sniffed by `wireshark` and opens the ips in tabs in `selenium`.

At first I tried using `whois` and `socket.gethostbyaddr()` as All I needed was to translate the ips to domains. But it didn't workout well.

I ran into a problem with permissions because `pyshark` needs root privilege and `selenium` doesn't work as root.

here is the code:

```
import pyshark
from selenium import webdriver

global ips


ips = ''
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/afterlife/Documents/chrome_profiles/cyber")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/afterlife/Downloads/chromedriver', options=options)

def get_domain_name(ip_address):
    for line in ips:
        if ip_address not in line:
            ips += ip_address+'\n'
            browser.execute_script('''window.open(''' + ip_address + ''',"_blank");''')


capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface="wlp1s0")
capture.set_debug()
for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
    try:
        if hasattr(packet, 'http'):
            protocol = packet.transport_layer
            source_address = packet.ip.src
            source_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].srcport
            destination_address = packet.ip.dst
            destination_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].dstport
            print(destination_address)
            get_domain_name(destination_address)
    except:
        print("exception")
```

I tried to make `pyshark` work as non root but failed, I used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common` but it haven't effected `tshark` of `pyshark`.

I also tried using `os.setuid()` which I successfully used once but forgot/now it doesn't work. I used `0` for root and `1000` for my non-root user.

How would you accomplish what I want?
Thank you!